# Nextj.js loads wrong image

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, browser

I have a weird problem!
Sometimes Next.js loads another image that exists on the page instead of the image that I used.

As you can see in the first attached image there is an image on the page, but when I click on the image URL it loads a different image(Load the right one)

I see this problem randomly, and on random components!
Sometimes there aren't any problems on the page!

And everything will load okay after a hard refresh

Next.js version 14.0.4

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to be related to the sharp package?